# Are any two groups of order 23 isomorphic to each other?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have to decide whether the following statements are true or false, with proofs.

1. Any two abelian groups of order $23$ are isomorphic to each other
2. Any two abelian groups of order $25$ are isomorphic to each other

#### Progress

I know that if $p$ is prime, up to isomorphism, there is only one group of order $p$, but I thought that only applies to small orders, less than $8$.

Comment: What do you know about groups of prime order?

Comment: For the part about groups of order $25$, what *abelian* groups of order $25$ do you know about?

Comment: I know that if p is prime, up to isomorphism, there is only one group of order p, but I thought that only applies to small order.

Comment: What would 'small order' mean in this case?

Comment: I know C_25 is one of them.

Comment: Small order means less than 8

Comment: @Kyle: There's another abelian group of order 25. Do you know about direct products?

Comment: @Bungo: Is that C_5 cross C_5?

Comment: @Kyle: Yep, that's the one. Two other interesting facts that you may try to prove if you're so inclined: (1) these are the only two nonisomorphic abelian groups of order 25, (2) there are no nonabelian groups of order 25. The same statements generalize to any group of order $p^2$ where $p$ is any prime.

Comment: @Bungo: Thx. I see what u mean! I will try them later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In virtue of the Cauchy's theorem for groups, every group with order $23$ is cyclic, hence isomorphic to $C_{23}$. On the other hand, $C_{25}$ and $C_5\times C_5$ are not isomorphic, since in the latter there is no element with order $25$.

Comment: For the second part, I agree with you . As for the first part, do you mean there is only one group of order 23, which is C_23?

Comment: Up to isomorphisms, yes.

Comment: So how come there would be any other groups of order 23 to be isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Every group with 23 elements has an element with order 23, so it is generated by such an element. A isomorphism between two groups of order 23 is set once we map a generator of the first group into a generator of the second one.